# Создание алгоритма поиска букв в запрашиваемом слове

Tags: php, поиск, замена

Я начинающий пользователь PHP.

**Введение**

Есть небольшая задумка чтобы создать сервис для создания красивых открыток (изображений) из заданного слова. Начал делать но возникла проблема сами знаете почему). Помогите пожалуйста написать хотя бы алгоритм поиска по запрашиваемому слову и вывода значений из массива рандомно, а с подгонами изображений и их выводом я уже разобрался.

**Принцип действия скрипта**

Суть скрипта заключается в том, чтобы искать запрашиваемом слове например "авто", совпадения с ключами из массива $words и рандомно выдавал значения этих ключей $words для каждой буквы или нескольких букв.

Заранее благодарен!

**Сам код который я начал писать**

````
$words = array(
    'а' => 'letter_a.png',
    'в' => 'letter_v.png',
    'ав' => 'letter_av.png',
    'т' => 'letter_t.png',
    'то' => 'letter_to.png',
    'о' => 'letter_o.png'
);

if (isset($_POST['input_word'])) {
$word_value = $_POST['input_word'];


/* здесь у меня и началась проблема) */

}
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input_word" placeholder="Слово">
<button type="submit">Создать открытку</button>
</form>```
````

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagefttext.php всё уже изобретено

Comment: Да я знаком данной функцией, но дело в том что она не совсем подходит для реализации. Например по ссылке есть буквы https://pin.it/Y7mIOqO. Мой вопрос в том как мне составить из заданного слова пользователя именно слово из таких букв https://pin.it/Y7mIOqO  . И у меня как раз таки в коде ```$words = array(
    'а' => 'letter_a.png',
    'в' => 'letter_v.png',
    'ав' => 'letter_av.png',
    'т' => 'letter_t.png',
    'то' => 'letter_to.png',
    'о' => 'letter_o.png'
);``` и содержатся имена тех самых избражений